# How to set up Python interpreter in Emacs on OS X?

Tags: python, emacs, osx-leopard

I have emacs and python working on OSX, but I'd like to get a python interpreter working in a split window so I can view output as I code. Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While in `python-mode`, hit <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>!</kbd> or do an <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `py-shell` <kbd>RET</kbd>. Should work with defaults.

Comment: Thanks. I use it on almost all my emacs answers.